# python add to string after nth characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

is it possible to add a string to a string after so many characters? Fro example:

String 1:

```
'I program'
```

String 2:

```
' like to'
```

I would like to add string 2 into string one after 2 characters making the line read 'I like to program'. Sorry for the lack of direction I just can't seem to find anything related to doing something like this.

The only way i can think of doing this is to split the first string into a list and then construct a new string using the list and string2

```
list = string1.split()
string3 = list[0] + string2 + list[1]
```

Now this would work but surely there's a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Show what have you tried?

Comment: as above im sorry for the lack of direction I haven't even got a clue where to start, apart from appending something to a string my knowledge is limited in this field. The python docs on strings https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html don't seem to mention anything obvious the only way I would think possible is to convert the string into a list using the split function then reconstruct the string using the list and string 2

Comment: @twigg inserting into a string doesn't make conceptual sense, as strings are immutable. I think your current approach is fine - you could also insert individual words into the list (`list.insert` *does* exist) then '` '.join` them all back together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in Python support list-like indexing. So:

```
s = "I'm a little bit like a list"
s[0]
Out[7]: 'I'
s[-1]
Out[8]: 't'
s[6:16]
Out[14]: 'little bit'
```

Therefore:

```
s1 = 'I program'
s2 = ' like to'
s1[:1] + s2 + s1[1:]
Out[5]: 'I like to program'
```

Thanks, Tobias, for the edit suggestion.

Comment: Or just `s1[:1] + s2 + s1[1:]`

Answer (score 2):

You can work with indexes when using strings.
So, if you want to add a string `text` after `n` characters of string `s` , you can use:

```
result = s[:n] + text + s[n:]
```

But bear in mind that concatenating string additions `+` is costly. You can use

```
result = ''.join([s[:n] , text , s[n:]])
```

for a more efficient solution, especially when adding *lots and lots of strings*